# Can you have different types of primitive data types in a dynamic array?

Tags: data-structures, computer-science, dynamic-arrays, primitive-types

I am new to data structures in computer science. I am trying to find out about all the types of implementations of lists. I started with dynamic arrays and I wanted to know if it is possible to have different types of primitive data types in a dynamic array data structure.
I though that "dynamic" only means that you can remove, insert and add to your array without caring about its size. But do you have to care for the types of elements that there are in the array too ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The term you are searching for is `heterogeneous` repectivelly `homogenous`. Heterogenous lists can store different kind of elements, while homogenous lists are limited to one type of elements.

Python is a good example for heterogeneous lists. This is implemented by storing references to the different objects in the list. So from a technical point of view, they store homogenous references, but from a user perspective they store different types, such as integer, strings, and other objects.

Answer (score 1):

The term `dynamic data structure` only refers to its size/structure in runtime, as in it can change on runtime.

So for example, in C++ an array is a static data structure, whereas a vector or ordered_set is probably what you might call dynamic.

By having multiple data types in a data structure, what you are referring to is a dynamically typed language.

Any data structure will support multiple elements in it if the language is dynamically typed, such as python. The data structure itself need not be strictly dynamic for that to happen.